# Web Accessibility: Redundant link- Adjacent links go to the same URL for a tag <a href="javascript:void(0)">

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag2.0

code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" title="Start a Process link" style="">Start a Process link</a>
```

I am using wave tool for Web accessibility.
Wave tool gives error:

> Redundant link- Adjacent links go to the same URL.
> Ref : [WCAG 2.4.4 Link Purpose (In Context) (Level A)](https://webaim.org/standards/wcag/checklist#sc2.4.4)

I understand due to `href="javascript:void(0)"` it gives the error "Adjacent links go to the same URL."

But I have to run jQuery function (to check validation & set value before redirect) on click of the `<a>` tag.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: You should instead use an event listener. Hyperlinks should have an end point, `href="javascript:void(0)` is an anti pattern. You have a `role="button"` - so why not just use a `<button>` and make life really easy for yourself :-) hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error points out that there is another link element (anchor `<a>` with a valid `href` attribute or another element with `role="link"`) that has the same target. In your case it is very likely as the target (`href`) is `javascript:void(0)` and there's probably more than one link like that. So the Wave thinks that those links are the same thus flagging [WCAG 2.0 Success Criterion 2.4.4 Link Purpose (In Context)](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-refs.html).

## Solution

1. Ideally, use `<button>` (as was mentioned in the comment above) - it will handle all events naturally
2. If it's not possible:

   - change the target (it can be replaced with `href="#"`)
   - remove `role="button"` - it will overwrite all link behavior otherwise.
   - remove word "link" in both `title` and inner text is excessive - the role will be communicated to screen reader users from the markup, no need to add it in labels.

### Examples

```
<a href="#" title="Start a Process" style="">Start a Process</a>
```

Or

```
<button style="">Start a Process</button>
```